# How to pass bash commands as function arguments in bash?

Tags: bash

Here is my bash script where I am trying to pass the bash command as function arguments to the function. However, I get an error. I am assuming it is trying to run the command.

```
./test1.sh: line 19: find /etc -type f > /dev/null: No such file or directory
```

here is my entire script. why am I getting this error what is the reason behind this?

```
#!/bin/bash

run_time_cmd() {
    cmd="$1"
    TIMEFORMAT='%3lR'
    exec 3>&1 4>&2
    echo "print cmd"
    echo $cmd
    echo "running cmd = $cmd"
    time_val=$( { time $cmd  2>&1;  1>&3- 2>&4-; } 2>&1 )  # Captures time only.
    return time_val
}


test_find_time() {
    echo 'find test starting'
    path="/etc"
    cmd="find $path -type f > /dev/null"
    echo $cmd
    total_time=run_time_cmd "${cmd}"
    echo $'Time to access each file average in seconds = ' $total_time
    echo 'find test stopped'
    find_results=$total_time
}

test_find_time
```

Comment: Treating commands as strings fails except for trivial cases (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). In this case, I'd recommend defining a function that does what you want, then just pass its name. Or maybe use `eval`, but that comes with a whole bunch of opportunities for bizarre bugs.

Comment: Learn to use arrays. Read the bash manual.

Comment: @konsolebox An array wouldn't work in this case, since the command contains a redirect; arrays can handle complex arguments, but not with other shell syntax.

Comment: @GordonDavisson It's still better to store command arguments as arrays until evaluation where you merge it as a single string if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You never call the function. The line

```
total_time=run_time_cmd "${cmd}"
```

is non-sense. In general, a line

```
X=Y Z
```

in bash runs the program Z in an environment, which is like the environment of the caller, but the variable X is set to Y.

In your case, you take the whole content of `cmd` (i.e. the string `find /etc -type f > /dev/null`) as a **single command name** (including all the spaces) and try to execute it in an environment, where the variable `toatl_time` has been set to the string `run_time_cmd`. Since there is no executable file in your path with the funny name `'find /etc -type f > /dev/null'`, you get the error message which you mention in your question.

In order to have your function invoked, you have to actually **call** it, for instance by doing

```
total_time=$(run_time_cmd "$cmd")
```